# Characterization of compact operators in hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T:H \rightarrow H$ a compact operator, show that
> $$T=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \langle x,e_n \rangle v_n$$
> where $\{e_n\}$ is a orthonormal basis of $H$ and $\{v_n\}$ is a orthogonal set.

I try to emulate the prove of the spectral descomposition theorem but i dont sure to these is the right way, the hint of the book is "see the operator $TT^{*]$ but i dont see how ocupate these fact.
Any hint or suggestion i will very grateful.

Comment: This seems implausible. Assuming $T$ takes the desired form, by computing $Te_k$, we find that $v_k = Te_k$. But, there's no reason to assume that $\{Te_n\}$ is an orthogonal set. For example, $Tx = \langle x, e_1\rangle e_1 + \langle x, e_2 \rangle(e_1 + e_2)$ is a compact operator where $Te_1$ and $Te_2$ are not orthogonal.

Comment: @TheoBendit Change the basis

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Which basis, and to what?

Comment: The conclusion follows from the polar decomposition $T=U|T|,$ where $|T|=\sqrt{T^*T}$ and $U$ is a partial isometry.

Comment: $Te_1$ and $Te_2$ are not orthogonal in your example. But $Tf_1$ and $Tf_2$ might be orthogonal for another set of orthonormal vectors $f_1$ and $f_2$ and the same operator $T.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Agreed, but that seems not relevant to the problem as stated. What would (or even, "could") the $v_n$ be, if not $Te_n$?

Comment: Change $\{e_1,e_2\}$ to another orthonormal set $\{f_1,f_2\}$ where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are linear combinations of $e_1,e_2.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Oh, I see. I have been taking $\{e_n\}$ as fixed, but if it's allowed to vary with $T$, then yes, this would work.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_spaces)

Comment: @Ryszard is right!  Write $T = U|T|$ by the polar decomposition,  diagonalize $|T|$ as $\sum \langle x, e_n\rangle  e_n$,  and then
$T(x)=U|T|x = \sum \langle x, e_n\rangle  U(e_n)$,  and notice that $U$ is isometric on the range of $|T|$,  so the $v_n:=U(e_n)$ are othonormal.

Comment: @Ruy You missed adding nonnegative eigenvalues of $|T|$ in front of each term $\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$

Comment: Yes I did!  Thanks @Ryszard!  To be clear, each $\langle x,e_n\rangle$ in my comment above should be replaced by $a_n\langle x,e_n\rangle$.  One may then incorporate the $a_n$ into the $v_n$ which will then be orthogonal but no longer orthonormal.

Comment: It is better for the site if you post solutions as solutions.